# Hot chocolate - Filtering not working as expected

Tags: filtering, hotchocolate

I am using [hot chocolate filtering V13](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/fetching-data/filtering) and not getting desired result. i.e., I have a `JSON`  as following:

```
{
  "id": "b3d7768e-7a22-4109-9511-cdd17585267b",
  "createdDateTime": "2023-06-01T21:02:34.4800722+00:00",
  "earliestPaymentDate": "2023-05-31T07:00:00+00:00",
  "itemNumber": "abc123456",
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "dueDate": "2023-07-01T06:59:59+00:00",
      "eventId": null,
      "itemState": "Mismatched",
      "itemUpdateDateTime": "2023-06-01T21:07:26.284906+00:00",
      "type": "Part"
    },
    {
      "dueDate": "2023-07-01T06:59:59+00:00",
      "eventId": null,
      "itemState": "Mismatched",
      "itemUpdateDateTime": "2023-06-01T21:07:26.2849904+00:00",
      "type": null
    }
  ]
}
```

My return object look like this where `matchedEntries` and `mismatchedEntries` are simply filter on `itemState` property.

```
type EventDto {
  id: String
  itemNumber: String
  matchedEntries: [ItemDto]
  mismatchedEntries: [ItemDto]
}
```

When I write following query with filtering, then I expect `null` or `empty` result because there is `and` condition with 2 search criteria which does not exist but it still returns 2 records.

```
query {
  itemDetailsByItemNumber(
    itemNumber: ["abc123456"],
    where: {
     and: [
        { matchedEntries: { all: { itemState: { contains: "Mismatched" } } } },
        { matchedEntries: { all: { type: { contains: "Cars" } } } }
      ]
    }
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

Questions:

- Is my query wrong?
- Do filtering works differently then what I am expecting?